# Pictured link is my coding. How do I make a proper good graph?

Tags: r

[image]
Okay so I have an assignment where I need to conduct a graph that best represents the before and after affects of two streams. The graph(s) have to contain means and standard error for each stream in each year.. I cannot figure the proper coding for the graph. I continue to get errors and bad graphs. I will attach a sample of what the data looks like too.

A sample of the data, it changes to after at 51
[image]

Comment: Hi welcome to S0; please make your question reproducible and say what you have tried. There is lots of guidance on SO on how to do this: try [reprex]; its helpful if you present your data as a data.frame object along the lines of `df <- data.frame(a = c(...), b = c(...))` with data relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to post a reproducible error or specification of your problem.
As far as I can analyze your problem, you maybe should not create `b4`, because it does not seem to be an effective subset. If you want to assemble certain plots, you can use `plot_grid` from [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html). 
Otherwise you can add `facet_wrap(~ VARIABLE_NAME)` to `ggplot` in order to create many plots divided by deviating observations in the specified variable.
If you are not happy with the visual outcome and result of your graph, you can choose another theme, e.g. `theme_bw()` which can be simply added to your `ggplot` function. You can add and change further labels with `labs()` and `theme()`.